# How to run multiple ECS tasks on the same server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk

I am trying to get multiple ECS tasks to run on the same EC2 server. It is a g4dn.xlarge which has 1GPU, 4CPU, and 16GB of memory.

I am using this workaround to allow the GPU to be shared between tasks. https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/327

However, when I launch multiple tasks, the second one gets stuck in a provisioning state until the first one finishes.

CloudWatch shows that the CPUUtilization is below 50% for the entire duration of each task.

This is my current CDK:

```js
const taskDefinition = new TaskDefinition(this, 'TaskDefinition', {
    compatibility: Compatibility.EC2
})

const container = taskDefinition.addContainer('Container', {
    image: ContainerImage.fromEcrRepository(<image>),
    entryPoint: ["python", "src/script.py"],
    workingDirectory: "/root/repo",
    startTimeout: Duration.minutes(5),
    stopTimeout: Duration.minutes(60),
    memoryReservationMiB: 8192,
    logging: LogDriver.awsLogs({
      logGroup: logGroup,
      streamPrefix: 'prefix',
    }),
})

const startUpScript = UserData.forLinux()
// Hack for allowing tasks to share the same GPU
// https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/327
startUpScript.addCommands(
      `(grep -q ^OPTIONS=\\"--default-runtime /etc/sysconfig/docker && echo '/etc/sysconfig/docker needs no changes') || (sed -i 's/^OPTIONS="/OPTIONS="--default-runtime nvidia /' /etc/sysconfig/docker && echo '/etc/sysconfig/docker updated to have nvidia runtime as default' && systemctl restart docker && echo 'Restarted docker')`
)

const launchTemplate = new LaunchTemplate(this, 'LaunchTemplate', {
    machineImage: EcsOptimizedImage.amazonLinux2(
        AmiHardwareType.GPU
    ),
    detailedMonitoring: false,
    instanceType: InstanceType.of(InstanceClass.G4DN, InstanceSize.XLARGE),
    userData: startUpScript,
    role: <launchTemplateRole>,
})

const autoScalingGroup = new AutoScalingGroup(this, 'AutoScalingGroup', {
    vpc: vpc,
    minCapacity: 0,
    maxCapacity: 1,
    desiredCapacity: 0,
    launchTemplate: launchTemplate,
})

const capacityProvider = new AsgCapacityProvider(this, 'AsgCapacityProvider', {
    autoScalingGroup: autoScalingGroup,
})
cluster.addAsgCapacityProvider(capacityProvider)
```

Edit:

Issue still persists after assigning task definition the CPU and Memory amounts.

[image]

Comment: The actual CPU utilization isn't taken into account by ECS. ECS is looking at the CPU and RAM requirements in the individual ECS task definitions to determine if there is room on the server for another task. What are the CPU and RAM settings in your task definitions?

Comment: As you can see from the CDK, the task itself doesn't have any CPU or Memory requirements. The only thing that is specified is the soft memory amount (memoryReservationMiB) on the container (8gb).

Comment: The CDK generates default values for a bunch of things if you don't set them manually. Looking at the CDK code doesn't tell me what the final values deployed to AWS are. You need to look at your task definitions in the AWS console. If no value at all is being set, that may explain why ECS is currently behaving the way it is.

Comment: No values are set. When I go into the console and edit the task definition, both the task size CPU and Memory are blank. Should these be set to 2 vCPU and 8gb respectively? I assumed that by leaving them blank they would share resources equally.

Comment: I have no idea what ECS does with those are blank. I didn't even know that was an option. I mostly use Fargate where those are definitely required values. I assume leaving them blank is why ECS is behaving the way it currently is for you.

Comment: That did not work unfortunately, I've updated the post to include an image after assigning the CPU and Memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by setting both the task sizes and container sizes to less than the sum that is available on the instance. So, although the instance has 16gb RAM and 4vCPUs, there must be leftover RAM and CPU for the instance in order to assign new tasks. So 2 tasks that have 2vCPU & 8gb RAM won't work but if they both have 1vCPU and 4gb RAM, that will work.